# Error in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE questions
(
qid INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
submitterId VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
approverId VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
questionText TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
answerA VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
answerB VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
answerC VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
answerD VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
difficulty INT NOT NULL,
category INT NOT NULL,
correctAnswer INT NOT NULL,
selectionProb INT NOT NULL,
status INT NOT NULL
);
```

What is wrong with the above SQL command in MySQL?
im getting

**ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE
 questions
(
qid INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
submitterId VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
appr' at line 1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key.
2. BLOB/TEXT columns in key specification can't be used without a key length.

Thus, the correct SQL DDL shall be:

```
CREATE TABLE questions (
    qid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    submitterId VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    approverId VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    questionText TEXT NOT NULL,
    answerA VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    answerB VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    answerC VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    answerD VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    difficulty INT NOT NULL,
    category INT NOT NULL,
    correctAnswer INT NOT NULL,
    selectionProb INT NOT NULL,
    status INT NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

An idtentity-column must be declared as PRIMARY or UNIQUE

Comment: there is a UNIQUE constraint on questionText. Doesn't it do that already?

Answer (score 0):

Add `PRIMARY KEY (qid)` at the end of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `AUTO INCREMENT` `NOT NULL` and add `PRIMARY KEY` at the end.

```
CREATE TABLE questions
(
qid INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
submitterId VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
approverId VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
questionText TEXT NOT NULL,
answerA VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
answerB VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
answerC VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
answerD VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
difficulty INT NOT NULL,
category INT NOT NULL,
correctAnswer INT NOT NULL,
selectionProb INT NOT NULL,
status INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (qid)
);
```